# How I sort folders the way I want in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, files-folders

I want to sort folders in Window 10 in my own way. For example, let's say I have folder for Work and folder for Personal stuff and folder for Bills. I want the Work folder in Details View to become the first one (above the others). I tried sort by feature but I can't display it in the way I want it to be displayed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Explorer is not user-modifiable. You can't change how it sorts items, other than what's already available.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to use numbers. That way they will sort to the top alphabetically. You can also use 'special' ascii characters to force items even higher than numbers. [Be careful of these though, as not all characters work on all file systems.]

e.g.

```
§ special ascii
1 folder x
2 folder y
any other folder
```

> [image]

Comment: this is good but is there other ways? I don't like to see numbers as they can emphasize other meaning (e.g. a list of items).

Comment: No, not really. You can sort by many things but *'my arbitrary sort order'* is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Pin the 3 folders using Quick Access, from the context menu on the folders

[image]

Then re-order the Quick Access list by dragging the folder(s) up/down to suit

[image]